# Как осуществить прерывание в Android? Ищу подходящий архитектурный шаблон

Tags: java, android, архитектура, listener

Пожалуйста, наставьте на подходящий архитектурный шаблон, который делал бы что-то вроде прерываний в приложении по событиям службы.

Задача.

1. Допустим, у меня есть датчики, и в сервисе я их бесконечно обновляю по запросу к устройству.
2. Мне нужно уметь в любой момент запросить из сервиса актуальные показания датчиков.
3. Если я даже не обращаюсь к сервису, но он получил данные выходящие за безопасный диапазон, программа в любом месте должна быть прервана и на весь экран показано сообщение об ошибке и способах её устранения.

Как мне кажется, мне нужно, чтобы мой Service был "издателем", а Activity "подписчиками", которым присвоен Listener событий датчиков. Или нет? Как красивее это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать обратный вызов:

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myService = new MyService();
        myService.doSomething(this); // Передача this в качестве параметра для обратного вызова
    }

    public void onCallback() {
        // Обработка обратного вызова от сервиса
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Received callback from service");
    }
}
public class MyService {

    public void doSomething(MyActivity activity) {
        // Вызов метода обратного вызова из активности
        activity.onCallback();
    }
}
```